# SharePoint online master page customization

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, master-page, branding

I created a master page by creating a copy of `oslo.master` in by using SharePoint designer.

This is now available in `catalogs/masterpage` but when I try to apply it to my site using the master page option in site settings,  none of the pages in pages library  changes the master page.

However when I change a page's master page using designer it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to mention. This is in SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that only the pages in pages library is not changed the master page?

You need to set the customized master page as "Site Master Page": The site master page will be used by all publishing pages:

[image]